# How to update PySimpleGUI Listbox that reads an excel file

Tags: python, excel, listbox, pysimplegui

I am using python3.7 and this is the current code base(apologies for putting so much code but thought it would help overall)

```
def TRADE_ENTRY(df_names, df_underlyings,df_strategies, columns, param, out_path,recovery_path):
   nameUpdate =0
   strategyUpdate=0
   underlyingUpdate=0
   sg.theme('Dark Brown 1')
   listing = [sg.Text(u, size = param) for u in columns]
   header =   [[x] for x in listing]
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   core = [
   sg.Input(f"{now.month}/{now.day}/{now.year}",size = param),
   sg.Input(f"{now.hour}:{now.minute}:{now.second}",size = param),
   sg.Listbox(list(df_strategies.STRATEGIES), size=(20,2), enable_events=False, key='_PLAYERS0_'),
   sg.Listbox(['ETF', 'EQT', 'FUT', 'OPT', 'BOND'],enable_events=False,key='_PLAYERS20_',size = (20,2)),
   sg.Listbox(list(df_names.NAMES), size=(20,4), enable_events=False,key='_PLAYERS6_'),
   sg.Listbox( ['B', 'S'],size = (20,1),enable_events=False,key='_PLAYERS12_'),
   sg.Input(size = param),
   sg.Input(size = param),
   sg.CalendarButton('Calendar', pad=None, font=('MS Sans Serif', 10, 'bold'), 
                button_color=('yellow', 'brown'), format=('%d/%m/%Y'),  key='_CALENDAR_', target='_INP_'),
   sg.Input(size = param),
   sg.Listbox(list(df_underlyings.UNDERLYINGS), size=(20,4), enable_events=False,key='_PLAYERS2_'),
   sg.Listbox(['C', 'P', 'N/A'],size = param), 
   ]

   mesh = [[x,y] for (x,y) in list(zip(listing, core))]
   mesh[8].append(sg.Input(size = (10,2),key = '_INP_'))
   layout =[[sg.Button("SEND"),sg.Button("NEW_NAME"), sg.Button("NEW_STRAT"), sg.Button("NEW_UND")] ]+ mesh
   window = sg.Window('Trade Entry System', layout, font='Courier 12').Finalize()
   
   while True:
      event, values = window.read(timeout=500)
      #print('EVENT, VALUES', event, values)# all the inputs with extra information for compiler
      if event == "SEND":
         data = values
         a = list(data.values())

         a = [x if isinstance(x, list) == False else empty_handler(x) for x in a]
         a = [x if x !="" else "EMPTY" for x in a ]
         #print('A', a)#all the inputs now in a list
         df = pd.DataFrame(a, index = columns)
         print('DF1', df)#columns dataframe with column names and then the values
         df = df.transpose()
         #print('DF2', df)#rows dataframe with column names and then the values
         status = error_handling(df)
         #print('STATUS', status)
         if status == "ERROR":
            print("YOU MUST RECTIFY INPUT")

         elif status == "CORRECT":
            #if a future then will overwrite its name
            if df['TYPE'][0] == "FUT":
               df['NAME'][0] = "F-"+  df['UNDERLYING'][0] + "-" +df['EXPIRATION'][0] 
            #if an option then will overwrite its name
            elif df['TYPE'][0] =="OPT":
               df['NAME'][0] = 'O-' +  df['UNDERLYING'][0] + "--" + df['OPTION_TYPE'][0] +df['STRIKE'][0] +"--" +df['EXPIRATION'][0]
            else:
               pass 
            processing(df, recovery_path, out_path)
         else:
            print("ERROR WITH USER INPUT FATAL")
            break
       elif event == "NEW_NAME":
         security_creation(r'Y:\NAMES.xlsx', "Sheet1", "NAME", param)
         nameUpdate=1
         continue
      elif event == "NEW_STRAT":
         security_creation(r'Y:\STRATEGIES.xlsx', "Sheet1", "STRATEGY", param)
         strategyUpdate=1
         continue
      elif event == "NEW_UND":
         security_creation(r'Y:\UNDERLYINGS.xlsx', "Sheet1", "UNDERLYINGS", param)
         underlyingUpdate=1
         continue
         
      elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_KEY:
         if(nameUpdate==1):
            df_names = pd.read_excel(r'Y:\NAMES.xlsx', "Sheet1")
            df =df_names.values.tolist()
            window['_PLAYERS6_'].update(values=df, set_to_index=0)
         
         if(underlyingUpdate==1):
            df_underlyings = pd.read_excel(r'Y:\UNDERLYINGS.xlsx', "Sheet1")
            df =df_underlyings.values.tolist()
            window['_PLAYERS2_'].update(values=df, set_to_index=0)
         
         if(strategyUpdate==1):
            df_strategies = pd.read_excel(r'Y:\STRATEGIES.xlsx', "Sheet1")      
            df =df_strategies.values.tolist() 
            window['_PLAYERS0_'].update(values=df, set_to_index=0)
         
         print("Listboxes updated !")
      else:
         print("OVER")
         break
   window.close()

TRADE_ENTRY(df_names, df_underlyings,df_strategies, columns, param,out_path, recovery_path)
```

Towards the end of the function there's 3 elif, all NEW_NAME, NEW_STRAT and NEW_UND are the user submitting information to the corresponding 3 excel files. The function security_creation actually updates said excel files. Below that I am trying to update the Listboxes but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since i am so confused

Comment: `pd.read_excel` returns DataFrame or dict of DataFrames. Option `values` of method `update` should be `list`.

Comment: @JasonYang I have made those edits in the post above. Unfortunately currently it just prints 'Listboxes updated !' continuously. When i press NEW_NAME/NEW_STRAT/NEW_UND the window disappears and prints 'OVER'

Comment: Should check your code why some `if` condition not go. Case like `event == "NEW_NAME" and event== sg.TIMEOUT_KEY`, is it possible happened ?

Comment: `event == "NEW_NAME" and event== sg.TIMEOUT_KEY`, it means value of variable `event` is `"NEW_NAME"`, and also `None` at the same time. It is impossible, so `elif event == "NEW_NAME" and event== sg.TIMEOUT_KEY:` will be always False and do nothing.

Comment: @JasonYang I have made these edits and now the Listboxes are correctly updated, which is great. However due to the timeout=500 parameter, it seems the listboxes are being constantly updated and therefor don't allow scrolling down. So, I increased it to 5000 but now once i have selected something in the listbox it is changed after 5000.

Comment: Maybe you can set it to longer, like 10 minutes, `timeout=600000`. It is impossible to update GUI and scroll at the same time.

Comment: remember which item selected before update, then select it after update.

Comment: so this means i have to wait 10 minutes to see the update appear on the gui, this is not ideal. Would be great to simply update the excel file then display it instantly after submission but not have to see constant updating after that point. IS there a way to just say if change to the excel sheet then add it to the listbox without checking for changes at a given time interval?

Comment: All depend on your design, what condition to update is preferred.